# Locale: Codegen fails when instantiating with unit (code_pred: "Tactic failed")

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to use `code_pred` for an inductive predicate defined inside a locale. I came across this [email](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2017-February/msg00060.html) which shows how this can be done:

```
locale l = fixes x :: 'a assumes "x = x"
inductive (in l) is_x where "is_x x"
global_interpretation i: l "0 :: nat" defines i_is_x = "i.is_x" by unfold_locales simp

declare i.is_x.intros[code_pred_intro]
code_pred i_is_x by(rule i.is_x.cases)
```

However, when I change the `global_interpretation` to use `() :: unit` instead of `0 :: nat`, then `code_pred` fails with the following message:

```
Tactic failed
The error(s) above occurred for the goal statement⌂:
i_is_x_i x = Predicate.bind (Predicate.single x) (λx. case x of () ⇒ Predicate.single ())
```

I tried to do the prove manually, but at some point I got the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what is happening here, but the code generator already uses unit internally and the tactic (corresponding to `before single intro rule`) fails on your example.

The error does not come from the proof, but comes from proof done internally in the `done` part. So changing the proof does not change the issue (and you even see with sorry).

A possible work-around: use a type isomorphic to unit:

```
datatype myunit = MyUnit
locale l = fixes x :: 'a assumes "x = x"
inductive (in l) is_x where "is_x x"
definition X where ‹X = ()›
global_interpretation i: l "MyUnit :: myunit" defines i_is_x = "i.is_x" by unfold_locales simp

declare i.is_x.intros[code_pred_intro]

code_pred  i_is_x
  by (rule i.is_x.cases)
```

Comment: @AndreasLochbihler is a power user of code generation, but it might be faster to ask on the mailing list.

Comment: The error occurs when the predicate compiler tries to prove the code equations it has compiled from the intro rules. I don't know either what exactly goes wrong here. It seems that the proof strategy gets confused because the predicate compiler internally uses `unit` for some cases. Switching to a different `unit` type as suggested by Mathias seems to be the cheapest work-around. Alternatively, you can completely disable the proofs with the option `code_pred [skip_proof]`. This obviously avoids the error, but you then trust the predicate compiler to not miscompile the equations.